# observable collection with buttons and textblocks

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I have a `ObservableCollection` with many items. Each item has properties called `Text` and `Anzahl`. These 2 properties should be displayed in 2 different textblocks. I have already achieved that. In my `AppBar`, I have two Buttons. One to display the next item and one to step one back.

Can I achieve that with bindings? What is the easiest way?

Comment: To give an efficient solution to your problem, it would be helpful to see the code of what you've already acheived.

Comment: I have a observable collection called MainListe which includes a field called "Text" and "Anzahl". I bind these 2 to my texboxes. It works fine, but now i just want to switch with the buttons through the collection.

Comment: it is split over so many  huge classes that it is hard to filter the imortant Content. It would be great if you can tell me how to implement the buttons action, so the user can step through each item.

Comment: What is the `ObservableCollection ` binded to? ListBox? DataGrid? How are the `TextBlock` binded to a specific item in the list? are they defined in a DataTemplate of that container?

Comment: The Obeservable Collection is set as data context of the two textblocks. textblock.text is binding to the properties of each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all bind your "Next" and "Previous" Button to Command and in the Command Action, set properties "Foo" and "Bar" (which are properties binded to your respective textblocks) with respect to current element.

for iterating through your ObservableCollection maintain one index variable at class scope like

```
int iterator=0;
```

and in your actions(previous and next) do like this

```
public void NextAction()
{
    iterator++;
    Foo=MainList[iterator].Text;
    Bar=MainList[iterator].Anzal;
}

public void PreviousAction()
{
    iterator--;
    Foo=MainList[iterator].Text;
    Bar=MainList[iterator].Anzal;
}
```

And don't forget to implement RaisePropertyChange to your Foo and Bar properties' set method..

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, it's hard to help precisely when we don't have context. Distilling your problem to a minimal code representation would be extremely helpful. For example, Rushi Soni's answer will work if your controls are bound to individual properties on a class, but there is another answer if you've bound your `TextBlock`s directly to your `ObservableCollection`:

By default, non-list controls like `TextBlock` which are bound to a collection will display the "current" item in the list. WPF maintains a (somewhat magical) view of the collection that keeps track of the current item. You can access the collection view by calling `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ObservableCollection)` and manipulate the current item by using methods `MoveCurrentToPrevious`, `MoveCurrentToNext`, `IsCurrentBeforeFirst`, and `IsCurrentAfterLast` on the returned `ICollectionView` interface.

Full code for this scenario:

XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!-- the MyCollection type is derived from ObservableCollection<MyItem> -->
    <my:MyCollection x:Key="myCollection">
        <my:MyItem Text="One" Anzhal="1"/>
        <my:MyItem Text="Two" Anzhal="2"/>
        <my:MyItem Text="Three" Anzhal="3"/>
    </my:MyCollection>
</UserControl.Resources>

<!-- data context of the top level control is the observable collection defined here in XAML, but
could also be created and assigned in code -->
<DockPanel Name="grid1" DataContext="{StaticResource myCollection}"  >
    <!-- navigation controls -->
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="&lt; Previous" Name="buttonPrev" Click="buttonPrev_Click" />
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Next &gt;" Name="buttonNext" Click="buttonNext_Click" />
    </Grid>

    <!-- display of the current item -->
    <TextBlock Padding="5" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding Text}" />
    <TextBlock Padding="5" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding Anzhal}" />

    <!-- list display of all items (not necessary but helpful for visualizing the behavior) -->
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" DisplayMemberPath="Text" />
</DockPanel>
```

Class definitions for the collection and the contained items:

```
public class MyCollection : ObservableCollection<MyItem> { }

public class MyItem
{
    // NOTE: these must be get/set properties in order for binding to work
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Anzhal { get; set; }
}
```

And the code for handling the Next/Previous button clicks, which demonstrates wrapping around when reaching the ends of the collection:

```
ICollectionView GetView()
{
    // use FindResource() to retrieve the collection since it is defined in XAML
    // Then we retrieve WPF's view into the collection so we can manipulate the 
    // current item (next, previous)

    return CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(FindResource("myCollection"));
}

private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var view = GetView();

    // wrap around behavior
    view.MoveCurrentToNext();
    if (view.IsCurrentAfterLast) {
        view.MoveCurrentToFirst();
    }
}

private void buttonPrev_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var view = GetView();

    // wrap around behavior
    view.MoveCurrentToPrevious();
    if (view.IsCurrentBeforeFirst) {
        view.MoveCurrentToLast();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.